# Is there a javascript equivalent to unpack sequences like in python?

Tags: javascript, python, iterable-unpacking

Is there a javascript equivalent to unpack sequences like in python?

```
a, b = (1, 2)
```

Comment: Please change the accepted answer to the one by Anthony. It's 2018 - all modern browsers (and node.js) support it now.

Comment: Thanks for the input @noamtm. I changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
[a, b] = [1, 2]
```

**Update:**

Browser compatibility matrix:

- Firefox: all versions
- Opera: 9.x only
- Chrome: 49 and higher
- MSIE: no
- EdgeHTML: 14 (Browser version 31, released Feb. 2016)
- Safari: 7.1 (8 for Safari Mobile)

Comment: why? which implementations are affected? do you have further links?

Comment: In opera 10 works, in ff 3 works, in ie 8 doesn't, in chrome doesn't. Not universal indeed.

Comment: Well, for starters this code won't work in IE, Chrome or Safari implementations. I'm pretty sure major browser-wise this is only supported by Firefox and Opera.

Comment: @Alsciende I'm tempted to flag you comment as offensive for mentioning IE6 ;)

Answer (score 8):

There isn't. JavaScript doesn't have such syntax sugar.

Comment: this answer is less correct than mine. The accepted answer should be 'among modern browsers only Firefox has this feature'.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins and Marcin, it's in ECMAScript 2015: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. See @AntonyHatchkins's answer.

Answer (score -4):

An object cannot contain a reference to an integer, only its value. So I can't see any way to do what you ask in javascript.